# Which Windows 7 edition is recommended for VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

Which Windows 7 edition is recommended for VS2010 Ultimate edition?
Which minimum Windows 7 edition is recommended If:
a) Only VS2010 is installed
b) Only SQL server 2008 is installed
c) Both are installed

Comment: I really don't think it matters. Just don't use starter as you will be tied to 1 GB of ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter.  You can review the system requirements for the Ultimate edition in [this page.](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/ultimate)